# Revert back and make copy of a branch in git

Tags: git, github

I have a lot of commits in my branch:

```
commit 1
commit 2
commit 3
commit 4
```

I am at commit 4, and now want to go to commit 2 and copy content that were at commit 2 to another branch.

Basically, I want to push changes at commit 2 to the server, not the changes which were made at commit 4 using that another branch.

Comment: Are you looking to cherry pick commit 2 onto a separate branch?

Comment: Yes. But the issue is I have pushed these commits to the parent branch.

Comment: 1) You could revert commits 1,2, and 4; 2) move the current branch pointer back a few commits, cherry-pick commit 2, and force push; or 3) try some interactive rebasing magic.

Comment: As said in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003858/revert-back-and-make-copy-of-a-branch-in-git#comment71226113_42003907 _rewrite your question_

Answer (score 0):

You want to create `mynewbranch` which points 2 commits behind:

```
git branch mynewbranch HEAD~2
```

Instead, you can even push without creating a local branch:

```
git push origin HEAD~2:refs/heads/mynewbranch
```

Comment: It is copying the current changes, not the previous changes. For example, if I added some files in commit 4, the above command gives those too in new changes.

Comment: `git branch mynewbranch HEAD~2` creates a new branch `mynewbranch` that points 2 commits behind.

Comment: Let me rewrite my issues: I have a branch A, I commited four times and pushed it. Now, I want to copy content of second commit to another branch. Your answer is not working.

Comment: _"I want to copy content of second commit to another branch."_ In git, a branch is just a pointer to a commit. Also, when you say "content of second commit", do you refer to the changes it introduces from the first commit, or to its whole content, i.e. the worktree content when you checkout it?

Comment: "content of second commit": changes introduced in first commit

Comment: OK, then you want to _cherry-pick_ it: `git cherry-pick HEAD~2 mytargetbranch`.

Comment: @learner I feel it is worth pointing out that the `git branch` command in this answer will create a new branch which begins at your 'commit 2', but _does not switch to it_. You should next do `git checkout mynewbranch` to switch to your newly created branch.

Comment: @DanLowe It is copying the recent changes too when I am checking out to newbranch.

Comment: @learner Do you have uncommitted or untracked changes? Some things will follow you from one branch to the next because they are still incomplete.

Comment: I have a branchA whose parent is branchB whose parent is branchC

branchA <- branchB <- branchC

1. Now I made some changes in branchA and pushed.

2. Then I took pull from branchC and pushed.

3. Then I took pull from branchB and pushed.

Now, I want to go to step 1 and make copy to another branch from this. 

This is my whole issue.

I tried to go to previous version and copy from there:

git checkout -b NewBranch CommitPointAtStep1

It didn't work, means I copied all changes to NewBranch.

Comment: Please add the graph you expect (as it would be printed by `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`) to your original question. Your request is unclear.

Comment: @learner I think you need to rewrite your question to be a little more clear. Here in the comments you are talking about 3 different branches, but your question text only mentions a sequence of commits, you don't mention existing branches, only about making a new one. It is not clear what you have done so far, or what you want to do next.